# how to insert new record based on old record and make them different?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

For example, there is a table:

**Table:** `PATIENT_DETAIL`

```
PATIENT_NAME(varchar), 
DISEASE(varchar), 
SICK_DEGREE(number), 
START_TIME(date), 
END_TIME(date)
```

There are 1000 patients in the table and each may have different diseases. Some have disease A, some have disease B and some have disease C.

Now I want to insert an record for each patient that they have a new disease D, but I want them to have different degree of sickness. The number could be ranged from 1 to 1000.

I would like to do this but they all have the some degree:

```
INSERT INTO PATIENT_DETAIL
SELECT PATIENT_NAME, 
'DISEASE D', 
(select dbms_random.value(1,1000) num from dual), 
sysdate, 
sysdate
```

---

1000 rows inserted.

if the code (select dbms_random.value(1,1000) num from dual) generate 500, then all patient will have sickness degree of 500, but I want them to be different.

Comment: Why do you have the patient_name in every tuple, and not a patient_id?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't need to put `dbms_random.value(1,1000)` into a subselect. If you do, then the subselect is executed first and applied to all subsequent rows.

```
INSERT INTO PATIENT_DETAIL  
    SELECT PATIENT_NAME, 
          'DISEASE D', 
          dbms_random.value(1,1000), 
          sysdate, 
          sysdate
    FROM PATIENT_DETAIL
```

Comment: Thanks! I copied the code from a website which taught how to make random number in oracle.